# Calling :binary.match Erlang module from Elixir but having trouble with options

Tags: erlang, elixir

I aim to find within a string, starting at a certain index. It seems that [:binary.match/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#match-2) is what I look for, but I am having trouble with the options. From the documentation, it seems that it expects a list containing a single tuple, containing a scope and a part. I can't find anywhere what "scope" means, but I am also not sure if I am calling it correctly from Elixir.

Here are the kind of things that I am trying, but I keep getting an argument error:

```
:binary.match(my_str, "foo", [{[], {0, 100}}])

:binary.match(my_str, "foo", [{[], [start: 0, length: 100]}])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Erlang/OTP documentation could prove difficult to read, especially when coming from Elixir with its different syntax. For the record, atoms in Erlang typically start with a lowercase letter and variables with an uppercase letter, while variables in Elixir typically start with a lowercase letter and atoms with a colon. Here, `scope` is simply an atom.

Function `binary:match/3`, known as `:binary.match/3` from Elixir, takes a subject, a pattern and options as its arguments. Options is specified as:

```
Options = [Option]
Option = {scope, part()}
part() = {Start :: integer() >= 0, Length :: integer()}
```

which means it is a list of zero or more `Option` where `Option` is a tuple with `scope` atom as its first element and a `part()` as a second element. A `part()` is a tuple with two elements, `Start`, a non-negative integer, and `Length`, an integer (a negative length is allowed with a different, documented, meaning). Providing several scope options to `binary:match/3` is legal according to the specification yet this is not documented and the result is undefined.

To search a binary from a specific index to the end of the binary, use the tuple `{scope, {Start, Length}}` (or `{:scope, {start, length}}` in Elixir) with Start as the index (0-based) and Length as the size of the binary minus start.

If `Start` or `Start + Length` are beyond the input string, the function raises an exception as documented further down on the [page you linked to](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#match-3):

> If `{scope, {Start,Length}}` is specified in the options such that `Start` > size
>   of `Subject`, `Start + Length` < 0 or `Start + Length` > size of `Subject`, a `badarg` exception is raised.

Example usage with string "hello world" is the following:

```
binary:matches(<<"hello world">>, <<"o">>).
binary:match(<<"hello world">>, <<"o">>, [{scope, {0, byte_size(<<"hello world">>)}}]).
binary:match(<<"hello world">>, <<"o">>, [{scope, {5, byte_size(<<"hello world">>) - 5}}]).
```

These calls return `[{4,1},{7,1}]`, `{4,1}` and `{7,1}` respectively.

In Elixir syntax, this would be:

```
:binary.matches("hello world", "o")
:binary.match("hello world", "o", scope: {0, byte_size("hello world")})
:binary.match("hello world", "o", scope: {5, byte_size("hello world") - 5})
```

Indeed, `Options` can be considered a [Keyword list](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html), as all elements are tuples of two elements where the first is an atom. Brackets can be omitted, it is even considered [good practice](https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide#keyword-list-brackets) since options is optional and you could call `:binary.match/2` instead.

Please note that you should use `byte_size/1` here and not `String.length/1` as they do not (necessarily) return the same value. `String.length/1` returns the number of characters while `byte_size/1` returns the number of bytes - and this is what `binary:match/3` function expects (and returns). The difference occurs with non ASCII (7 bits) characters that are encoded as several bytes.

Comment: Outstanding answer!! Thank you for the detailed clarification. This will help me with understanding Erlang docs in the future. And I also appreciate that you explained an oddity that I noticed regarding byte_size / String.length

Comment: There is an extra curly bracket at the end of the last 2 elixir code examples.

Comment: @BobWoodley Thank you, fixed.